# Using Spring MVC how do I add a custom JsonSerializer for a java 8 LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm using Spring 4.1.6 to create a RESTful API. I am *not* using Spring Boot. I don't want to annotate each of my resources with `@JsonSerialize(using = MyLocalDateTimeJsonSerializer.class)` because it adds a lot of boilerplate. Rather, this should be the default behaviour.

Ideally, I'd like to add some configuration to pick up my custom `LocalDateTime` serializer that would then be used throughout. I saw an example that made me hopeful that the following would work but it does not.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class JacksonConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
       Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
        .serializers(new LocalDateTimeJsonSerializer());
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
    }

}

public class LocalDateTimeJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime localDateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString("foo");
    }

    @Override
    public Class<LocalDateTime> handledType() {
        return LocalDateTime.class;
    }

}
```

I note that Spring loads `JSR310Module` which calls `addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, LocalDateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE)` which is being used. Could it be that this is registered after the one in the example above and so taking preference?

Is there a way that I could have my custom `LocalDateTime` serializer used throughout the code, without using `@JsonSerialize`?

**EDIT**
The reason that Spring DI was not picking up the annotation based configuration is because my project had xml based configuration too, which had `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` declared.

This seemed to override the annotated class. Removing this from the xml, the configuration class, which extended `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` was component scanned and utilised.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your serializer/deserializer in a Module and expose it as a com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule.
Spring automaticaly registers al beans of type Module and will use them to configure the ObjectMapper.
I am using the follwoing code and it works :

```
@Component
public class CommonsModule extends SimpleModule implements RegisterableModule {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public CommonsModule() {
        addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, 
new LocalDateTimeJsonSerializer());
    }
}
```